# When does using C# structs (value types) sacrifice performance?

Tags: c#, performance, struct, non-nullable, value-type

I have been playing with structs as a mechanism to implicitly validate complex value objects, as well as generic structs around more complex classes to ensure valid values.  I am a little ignorant as to the performance consequences, so I am hoping you all can help me out.  For example, if I were to do something like injecting a domain object into a value type wrapper, would that cause problems ? Why?  I understand the difference between value types and reference types, and my goal here is to leverage the different behavior of value types.  What exactly do I need to look into in order to do this responsibly?

Here is an extremely basic idea of something I was thinking.

```
public struct NeverNull<T>
    where T: class, new()
{

    private NeverNull(T reference)
    {
        _reference = reference;
    }

    private T _reference;

    public T Reference
    {
        get
        {
            if(_reference == null)
            {
                _reference = new T();
            }
            return _reference;
        }
        set
        {
            _reference = value;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator NeverNull<T>(T reference)
    {
        return new NeverNull<T>(reference);
    }

    public static implicit operator T(NeverNull<T> value)
    {
        return value.Reference;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, one nasty thing is that this doesn't behave as you might expect it to naively:

```
NeverNull<Foo> wrapper1 = new NeverNull<Foo>();
NeverNull<Foo> wrapper2 = wrapper1;

Foo foo1 = wrapper1;
Foo foo2 = wrapper2;
```

That's going to create *two* instances of `Foo` because the original version was copied, before `wrapper1` created an instance.

Basically, you're dealing with a mutable struct - which is almost *never* a nice thing to have. Additionally, I'm not generally keen on implicit conversions.

It feels like you're trying to achieve magic-looking code here... and I'm generally against that sort of thing. *Maybe* it makes sense for your particular use case, but I can't think of where I'd personally want to use it.

Comment: I was aware of the behavior you described.  However, if it were undesirable, I see a method to circumvent the 'copying problem'.

Instead of in the instance of the NeverNull, the references could be stored in a static dictionary.  Then the NeverNull would store the hashcode to the dictionary.  It seems to me this would result in the same type of functionality without copying references.  

The purpose of the implicit cast is to make working with the reference type easier, while preserving a non-nullable constraint.

Comment: This actually brings up another question.  Do static members of structs behave differently than static members of classes?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @smartcaveman: It sounds like you're adding layers of magic on top of each other... I rarely find I'm in a situation where I'd be happy with a new "empty" instance being constructed if it wasn't otherwise present. As for static members - no, they're basically the same between structs and classes.

Comment: I agree with you.  I used this class as a simple example.  Something more realistic that I have working in my solution is a ReadOnlyLazy<T> which makes a static call to my IoC Container.  It ends up being quite effective and simplifies my dependencies, without exposing the container directly.  (this is only used for private readonly fields)

Comment: @smartcaveman: Are you using .NET 4? If so, I'd just use `Lazy<T>` to start with :)

Comment: 3.5 ...  I didn't know about that class and I just looked at the documentation, but it seems like it is nullable.  This means it requires initialization (subject to human error) and would be more complex in wiring to an IoC container.

Comment: @smartcaveman: No, as `Lazy<T>` is a class, and there's no implicit conversion. Have a look at it though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx

Comment: Do you have a reason for advocating using Lazy<T>, initialized in the constructor by an IoC container, rather than a value type which makes the static call internally, and only requires the type in the definition?

Comment: Thanks again for all your help.  I found this link on in a post on the right.  I know you said you can't think of where you'd personally like to use something like this, but I think you might get a kick out of ... http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/06/non-nullable-reference-types.aspx

Comment: @smartcaveman: There's a difference between my blog post and your version though - mine just wraps an existing non-null reference, rather than creating a new instance. And there are all the downsides I mention in the blog post, too :)

Comment: @smartcaveman: The semantics I think you're after are simply unobtainable in .net.  The problem is that there's no way to distinguish `var A = new someStruct(); var B = new someStruct();` from `var A = new someStruct; var B = A;` (nor, for that matter `var A = new AnyType[2];` from `var A = new AnyType[2]; A[1] = A[0];`.  A static dictionary won't help if there's no way to tell that one default instance has been copied over another default instance.

Answer (score 7):

As Jon correctly points out, the problem here is that the behaviour of the type is *unexpected*, not that it is *slow*. From a performance perspective, the overhead of the struct wrapper around the reference should be very low.

If what you want to do is to represent a non-nullable reference type then a struct is a reasonable way to do it; however, I would be inclined to make the struct immutable by losing the "auto creation" feature:

```
public struct NeverNull<T> where T: class 
{ 
    private NeverNull(T reference) : this()
    { 
        if (reference == null) throw new Exception(); // Choose the right exception
        this.Reference = reference; 
    } 

    public T Reference { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator NeverNull<T>(T reference) 
    { 
        return new NeverNull<T>(reference); 
    } 

    public static implicit operator T(NeverNull<T> value) 
    { 
        return value.Reference; 
    } 
}
```

Make the caller responsible for providing a valid reference; if they want to "new" one up, let 'em.

Note also that generic conversion operators can give you unexpected results. You should read the spec on conversion operators and understand it thoroughly. For example, you cannot make a non-null wrapper around "object" and then have that thing implicitly convert to the unwrapping conversion; every implicit conversion to object will be a boxing conversion on the struct. You cannot "replace" a built-in conversion of the C# language.

Comment: Do you know off hand where to find official documentation on generic conversion operators?  I'm familiar with everything here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473(v=VS.80).aspx, but did not see anything with specific focus on generics.

Comment: @smartcaveman: Read sections 6.4 and 10.10.3 of the specification.

Comment: What's the point of that structure?  If one says `NeverNull<Form> SupposedlyNonNullForm = default(NeverNull<Form>)`, then `SupposedlyNonNullForm.Reference will be `null`.  Further, that `NeverNull<Form>` variable can be copied just fine to any other `NeverNull<Form>` without complaint.  The only way I could see a `NeverNull<T>` as being useful would be if `T` was an immutable class type, there was a mutable static `DefaultReference` property, and the `Reference` property returned `DefaultRefernece` when the backing field was null.

Answer (score 2):

The main penalty is with **boxing** for structs. Also they are passed by value so a large struct when passed to a method will have to be **copied**:

```
MyStruct st;
foo.Bar(st); // st is copied
```

Comment: +1 for addressing a performance concern, which is what this question is asking about.  This MSDN article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28VS.71%29.aspx) briefly discusses situations where it might be more efficient to use a value type, though it doesn't directly address the converse: when is it not efficient to use a value type.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, just a note on the above.

MyStruct st;
foo.Bar(st); // st is copied

This isn't boxing, unless the parameter of Bar is object for example.

```
void Bar(MyStruct parameter){}
```

would not box the value type.

Parameters are passed by value in c# by default, unless you use the ref or out keyword. Parameters passed by value are copied. The difference between passing the struct and the object is what is passed. With a value type, the actual value is copied in, which means a new value type is created, so you end up with a copy. With a reference type the reference to the reference type is passed in. Clues in the name I guess :)

So there is a performance hit for structs because the whole structure is copied unless you use the ref/out keyword, and if you're doing that extensively, I think your code needs looking at.

Boxing is the process of assigning a value type to a reference type variable. A new reference type (object) is created and a copy of the value type assigned into it.

I sort of got what you were doing in the original code, but it seems to be solving one simple problem with one that has many implicit rather than explicit complexities.

Comment: I did not say it boxes. I mentioned 2 issues, one boxing one copy. It clearly says that in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

The answers in this question seem to have moved away from discussing performance and instead are addressing the dangers of mutable value types.

Just in case you find this useful, here is an implementation that i threw together that does something similar to your original example using an immutable value type wrapper.

The difference is that my value type doesn't directly reference the object to which it refers; instead it holds a key and references to delegates that perform either a lookup using the key (TryGetValueFunc) or a create using the key.  (Note:  my original implementation had the wrapper holding a reference to an IDictionary object, but I changed it to a TryGetValueFunc delegate just to make it a bit more flexible, though that may be more confusing, and I'm not 100% sure that doing so didn't open up some kind of flaw).

Note, though, that this could still result in unexpected behavior (depending on what you expect), if you are manipulating the underlying data structures that the wrapper accesses.

Below is a complete working example, along with a usage example for a console program:

```
public delegate bool TryGetValueFunc<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, out TValue value);

public struct KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>
{
    private bool _KeyHasBeenSet;
    private TKey _Key;
    private TryGetValueFunc<TKey, TValue> _TryGetValue;
    private Func<TKey, TValue> _CreateValue;

    #region Constructors

    public KeyedValueWrapper(TKey key)
    {
        _Key = key;
        _KeyHasBeenSet = true;
        _TryGetValue = null;
        _CreateValue = null;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(TKey key, TryGetValueFunc<TKey, TValue> tryGetValue)
    {
        _Key = key;
        _KeyHasBeenSet = true;
        _TryGetValue = tryGetValue;
        _CreateValue = null;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        _Key = key;
        _KeyHasBeenSet = true;
        _TryGetValue = null;
        _CreateValue = createValue;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(TKey key, TryGetValueFunc<TKey, TValue> tryGetValue, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        _Key = key;
        _KeyHasBeenSet = true;
        _TryGetValue = tryGetValue;
        _CreateValue = createValue;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(TryGetValueFunc<TKey, TValue> tryGetValue)
    {
        _Key = default(TKey);
        _KeyHasBeenSet = false;
        _TryGetValue = tryGetValue;
        _CreateValue = null;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(TryGetValueFunc<TKey, TValue> tryGetValue, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        _Key = default(TKey);
        _KeyHasBeenSet = false;
        _TryGetValue = tryGetValue;
        _CreateValue = createValue;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        _Key = default(TKey);
        _KeyHasBeenSet = false;
        _TryGetValue = null;
        _CreateValue = createValue;
    }

    #endregion

    #region "Change" methods

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(TKey key)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(key, _TryGetValue, _CreateValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(TKey key, TryGetValueFunc<TKey, TValue> tryGetValue)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(key, tryGetValue, _CreateValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(key, _TryGetValue, createValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(TKey key, TryGetValueFunc<TKey, TValue> tryGetValue, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(key, tryGetValue, createValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(TryGetValueFunc<TKey, TValue> tryGetValue)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(_Key, tryGetValue, _CreateValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(TryGetValueFunc<TKey, TValue> tryGetValue, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(_Key, tryGetValue, createValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(_Key, _TryGetValue, createValue);
    }

    #endregion

    public TValue Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_KeyHasBeenSet)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("A key must be specified.");

            if (_TryGetValue == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("A \"try get value\" delegate must be specified.");

            // try to find a value in the given dictionary using the given key
            TValue value;
            if (!_TryGetValue(_Key, out value))
            {
                if (_CreateValue == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("A \"create value\" delegate must be specified.");

                // if not found, create a value
                value = _CreateValue(_Key);
            }
            // then return that value
            return value;
        }
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();

        Func<string, Foo> createValue = (key) =>
        {
            var foo = new Foo { ID = key };
            dictionary.Add(key, foo);
            return foo;
        };

        // this wrapper object is not useable, since no key has been specified for it yet
        var wrapper = new KeyedValueWrapper<string, Foo>(dictionary.TryGetValue, createValue);

        // create wrapper1 based on the wrapper object but changing the key to "ABC"
        var wrapper1 = wrapper.Change("ABC");
        var wrapper2 = wrapper1;

        Foo foo1 = wrapper1.Value;
        Foo foo2 = wrapper2.Value;

        Console.WriteLine("foo1 and foo2 are equal? {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(foo1, foo2));
        // Output: foo1 and foo2 are equal? True

        // create wrapper1 based on the wrapper object but changing the key to "BCD"
        var wrapper3 = wrapper.Change("BCD");
        var wrapper4 = wrapper3;

        Foo foo3 = wrapper3.Value;
        dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Foo>(); // throw a curve ball by reassigning the dictionary variable
        Foo foo4 = wrapper4.Value;

        Console.WriteLine("foo3 and foo4 are equal? {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(foo3, foo4));
        // Output: foo3 and foo4 are equal? True

        Console.WriteLine("foo1 and foo3 are equal? {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(foo1, foo3));
        // Output: foo1 and foo3 are equal? False
    }
}
```

Alternative implementation using `IDictionary<string, Foo>` instead of `TryGetValueFunc<string, Foo>`.  Note the counter-example I put in the usage code:

```
public struct KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>
{
    private bool _KeyHasBeenSet;
    private TKey _Key;
    private IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _Dictionary;
    private Func<TKey, TValue> _CreateValue;

    #region Constructors

    public KeyedValueWrapper(TKey key)
    {
        _Key = key;
        _KeyHasBeenSet = true;
        _Dictionary = null;
        _CreateValue = null;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(TKey key, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        _Key = key;
        _KeyHasBeenSet = true;
        _Dictionary = dictionary;
        _CreateValue = null;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        _Key = key;
        _KeyHasBeenSet = true;
        _Dictionary = null;
        _CreateValue = createValue;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(TKey key, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        _Key = key;
        _KeyHasBeenSet = true;
        _Dictionary = dictionary;
        _CreateValue = createValue;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        _Key = default(TKey);
        _KeyHasBeenSet = false;
        _Dictionary = dictionary;
        _CreateValue = null;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        _Key = default(TKey);
        _KeyHasBeenSet = false;
        _Dictionary = dictionary;
        _CreateValue = createValue;
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper(Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        _Key = default(TKey);
        _KeyHasBeenSet = false;
        _Dictionary = null;
        _CreateValue = createValue;
    }

    #endregion

    #region "Change" methods

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(TKey key)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(key, _Dictionary, _CreateValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(TKey key, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(key, dictionary, _CreateValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(key, _Dictionary, createValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(TKey key, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(key, dictionary, createValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(_Key, dictionary, _CreateValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(_Key, dictionary, createValue);
    }

    public KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue> Change(Func<TKey, TValue> createValue)
    {
        return new KeyedValueWrapper<TKey, TValue>(_Key, _Dictionary, createValue);
    }

    #endregion

    public TValue Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_KeyHasBeenSet)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("A key must be specified.");

            if (_Dictionary == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("A dictionary must be specified.");

            // try to find a value in the given dictionary using the given key
            TValue value;
            if (!_Dictionary.TryGetValue(_Key, out value))
            {
                if (_CreateValue == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("A \"create value\" delegate must be specified.");

                // if not found, create a value and add it to the dictionary
                value = _CreateValue(_Key);
                _Dictionary.Add(_Key, value);
            }
            // then return that value
            return value;
        }
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // this wrapper object is not useable, since no key has been specified for it yet
        var wrapper = new KeyedValueWrapper<string, Foo>(new Dictionary<string, Foo>(), (key) => new Foo { ID = key });

        // create wrapper1 based on the wrapper object but changing the key to "ABC"
        var wrapper1 = wrapper.Change("ABC");
        var wrapper2 = wrapper1;

        Foo foo1 = wrapper1.Value;
        Foo foo2 = wrapper2.Value;

        Console.WriteLine("foo1 and foo2 are equal? {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(foo1, foo2));
        // Output: foo1 and foo2 are equal? True

        // create wrapper1 based on the wrapper object but changing the key to "BCD"
        var wrapper3 = wrapper.Change("BCD");
        var wrapper4 = wrapper3;

        Foo foo3 = wrapper3.Value;
        Foo foo4 = wrapper4.Value;

        Console.WriteLine("foo3 and foo4 are equal? {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(foo3, foo4));
        // Output: foo3 and foo4 are equal? True

        Console.WriteLine("foo1 and foo3 are equal? {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(foo1, foo3));
        // Output: foo1 and foo3 are equal? False


        // Counter-example: manipulating the dictionary instance that was provided to the wrapper can disrupt expected behavior
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();

        var wrapper5 = wrapper.Change("CDE", dictionary);
        var wrapper6 = wrapper5;

        Foo foo5 = wrapper5.Value;
        dictionary.Clear();
        Foo foo6 = wrapper6.Value;

        // one might expect this to be true:
        Console.WriteLine("foo5 and foo6 are equal? {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(foo5, foo6));
        // Output: foo5 and foo6 are equal? False
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Something similar was discussed in the comments section of Jon's post.

Answer (score 1):

Another performance problem comes when you put structs in collections.  For example, imagine you have a `List<SomeStruct>`, and you want to modify the `Prop1` property of the first item in the list.  The initial inclination is to write this:

```
List<SomeStruct> MyList = CreateList();
MyList[0].Prop1 = 42;
```

That's not going to compile.  In order to make this work you have to write:

```
SomeStruct myThing = MyList[0];
myThing.Prop1 = 42;
MyList[0] = myThing.Prop1;
```

This causes two problems (primarily).  First, you end up copying the entire struct twice:  once into your working `myThing` instance, and then back to the list.  The second problem is that you can't do this in a `foreach` because it changes the collection and will cause the enumerator to throw an exception.

By the way, your `NeverNull` thing has a rather odd behavior.  It's possible to set the `Reference` property to `null`.  It strikes me as very very strange that this statement:

```
var Contradiction = new NeverNull<object>(null);
```

Is valid.

I would be interested to know the reasons you have for trying to create this type of struct.

Comment: The reference property can be set to null, however that null value can never be accessed.  Setting the Reference = null would in effect be the same as setting the reference property to its default value, a new T().

Comment: This bit about the collections is actually quite valueable.  My solution would be to create an extension method, to List<T> where T: struct, with a signature void ChangeValue(int index, Action<T> changeAction)

Comment: @smartcaveman: You'd need a delegate which took a `ref` parameter of type `T`.  The idea of an `AccessValueAt` method which would pass a list item as a `ref` parameter is a good one, but the only way to achieve such a thing is for the method in question to pass the appropriate element of the backing array as a `ref` parameter, and there's no way classes derived from `List` can get access to the necessary array.